# How to write ES query: field exists AND has value

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to write an ElasticSearch query that finds documents where a certain field exists AND has a particular value. I've tried doing the following:

```
query = {
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {'exists': {'field': 'A'}},
                {'term': {'A': 'value1'}}
            ]
        }
    }
}

es.search('my_index', body=query)
```

But I get back:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: {\n  "bool" : {\n    "must" : [\n      {\n        "exists" : {\n          "field" : "A",\n          "boost" : 1.0\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        "term" : {\n          "A" : {\n            "value" : "value1",\n            "boost" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    "disable_coord" : false,\n    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,\n    "boost" : 1.0\n  }\n}')

...
```

How can I write this type of query?

**Update**

Looks like I wasn't able to construct this query because the field 'A' isn't indexed, so I couldn't do a term query. In case it helps others, here's how I was able to find that out:

```
curl -s -u <user>:<pass> '<address>:9200/my_index/_search?error_trace=true' -d \
'{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"A"}},{"term":{"A":"value1"}}]}}}'

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: 
{\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"exists\" : {\n          \"field\" : \"A\",\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        \"term\" : {\n          \"A\" : {\n            \"value\" : \"value1\",\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"disable_coord\" : false,\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}","index_uuid":"uuid1","index":"my_index","stack_trace":"[my_index/x] 
QueryShardException[failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"exists\" : {\n          \"field\" : \"A\",\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      },\n      {\n        \"term\" : {\n          \"A\" : {\n            \"value\" : \"value1\",\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"disable_coord\" : false,\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}]; 
nested: IllegalArgumentException[Cannot search on field [A] since it is not indexed.]
```

Comment: Can you show the error that you get in your ES server logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to those logs.

Comment: Then can you share the full `RequestError`, it seems cut off above

Comment: Didn't think it was very informative -- but I've updated it.

Comment: nothing else you can share?

Comment: No other information, unfortunately. I think there might just be some syntax rules about mixing 'exists' with other types of queries -- the query I pasted above works just fine if I remove the term query. I just need help finding out what the rules are.

Comment: what do you get when you run this? `curl -XPOST 'http://<server:9200>/my_index/_search?error_trace=true' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"A"}},{"term":{"A":"value1"}}]}}}'`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful debugging suggestion! It turns out that the field wasn't indexed, so while I could do a query that determined whether or not it exists, I couldn't do a term query.

Comment: Cool, any helpful error you get that you can paste above (so that it gets indexed in the search engine and others can find it too)?